# How to disable all inline styles inside an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a class of **span** elements in which tinymce-generated texts are embedded.

```html
<span class="ArticleSummary">
This text is generated with a text editor and may have a lot of inline stylings.
</span>
```

This text is normally full of elements with inline styling. How can I disable all the inline stylings of that text and get pure html of it to be able to style the whole span outside with other css code?

Comment: What are you expecting as the final output?

Comment: @epascarello I just wanna get pure html and then use some other styling for the whole span which is not affected by inlines.

Comment: So... none of the answers below work? I wonder why mine was downvoted?

Comment: @webzy probably because you used jQuery and there is no reference to jQuery in this. Not everyone uses jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Loop over all the elements and delete all the style attributes.

```js
var mySpan = document.querySelector('span');

var elements = mySpan.querySelectorAll("*");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].removeAttribute("style");
}
```

```html
<span>
  <a href="http://example.com/" style="color: red;">Hello <strong>World</strong></a> — <cite style="text-decoration: overline;">Brian Kernighan</cite>
  </span>
```

Comment: If you assign a class for the span to make that work for only that class of spans, then how would that code change? I'm not very professional in Javascript.

Comment: @Stackcrawler — This code doesn't do anything with classes, and the question doesn't mention classes at all.

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the question, now.